# How can get value of element inside scrollView header webix

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, webix

I have a scrollview

In directive file, I have a code for generate a scrollView from webix, I have a scrollview which has header and body.

```
scrollview id:"scrollViewId"{
header: "<span class="abc"> value </span>"
},
body:{
}
```

How can I change value of tag span of scrollview from services file.

```
I guess that: $$("scrollViewId").get("span").setValue("valueChange");
```

Can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in angular way, Like

```
<span class="abc"> {{value}} </span>
```

and in your controller scope define `value`, Like

```
$scope.value = "valueChange"
```

This way the value is shown inside the span.